# Difference between action of a Slider and a HorizontalGauge

Tags: dynamic, gui-construction

First time posting. I am working on creating some interactive materials for the engineering classes that I teach and have run into an issue that I cannot puzzle out. I am using a slider to allow for a user to interactively change parameters but I also want to allow for the user to change the range of the slider. When I implement this using the standard `Slider` everything works fine, however, if I replace the `Slider` with a `HorizontalGauge`, I get a situation where the pointer does not update smoothly.

So this works fine...

```
DynamicModule[{y = 1, LowerLimit = 1, UpperLimit = 10},
Column[{
   Row[{
     PopupMenu[Dynamic[LowerLimit], {1, 2, 3, 4}],
     PopupMenu[Dynamic[UpperLimit], {5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}]
     }],
   Dynamic[Slider[Dynamic[y], {LowerLimit, UpperLimit}]],
   Framed[
    Row[{
      "Slider Value", Spacer[10], Dynamic[y], Spacer[20], 
      "Lower Limit", Spacer[10], Dynamic[LowerLimit], Spacer[20], 
      "Upper Limit", Spacer[10], Dynamic[UpperLimit]
      }]
    ]
   }]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But with `Slider` replaced with `HorizontalGauge`, I run into problems...

```
DynamicModule[{y = 1, LowerLimit = 1, UpperLimit = 10},
 Column[{
   Row[{
     PopupMenu[Dynamic[LowerLimit], {1, 2, 3, 4}],
     PopupMenu[Dynamic[UpperLimit], {5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}]
     }],
   Dynamic[HorizontalGauge[Dynamic[y], {LowerLimit, UpperLimit}]],
   Framed[
    Row[{
      "Slider Value", Spacer[10], Dynamic[y], Spacer[20], 
      "Lower Limit", Spacer[10], Dynamic[LowerLimit], Spacer[20], 
      "Upper Limit", Spacer[10], Dynamic[UpperLimit]
      }]
    ]
   }]
     ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Any suggestions and/or explanations would be greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think `HorizontalGauge` is just buggy. It shouldn't trigger a dynamic update when you change its state but it does. Simplest case:

```
HorizontalGauge[Dynamic[x]] // Dynamic
```

I would try using this "fixed" version

```
horizontalGauge = Refresh[HorizontalGauge[##], None] &
```

By the way, you could stick this into the built-in symbol's definition, and perhaps if you are convinced, add it to an `init.m` autoload file

```
HorizontalGauge;
Unprotect[HorizontalGauge];
Module[{guard = True},
  PrependTo[DownValues[HorizontalGauge],
   HoldPattern[HorizontalGauge[args___] /; guard] :> 
    Block[{guard = False}, 
     Refresh[HorizontalGauge[##], None] &[args]]]];
Protect[HorizontalGauge];
```

Comment: Nice! This works very well. Didn't you use this `Refresh[..., None]` trick elsewhere recently?

Comment: @rm-rf, yes to fix `Histogram`, in the same way

Comment: Ah, yes. That's the one.

Answer (score 3):

Adding the option `TrackedSymbols :> {LowerLimit, UpperLimit}` to the `Dynamic[..]` that holds `HorizontalGauge` fixes the issue:

```
 DynamicModule[{y = 1, LowerLimit = 1, UpperLimit = 10}, 
 Column[{Row[{PopupMenu[Dynamic[LowerLimit], {1, 2, 3, 4}], 
 PopupMenu[Dynamic[UpperLimit], {5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}]}], 
 Dynamic[HorizontalGauge[Dynamic[y], {LowerLimit, UpperLimit}], 
     TrackedSymbols :> {LowerLimit, UpperLimit}], 
 Framed[Row[{"Slider Value", Spacer[10], Dynamic[y], Spacer[20], 
  "Lower Limit", Spacer[10], Dynamic[LowerLimit], Spacer[20], 
  "Upper Limit", Spacer[10], Dynamic[UpperLimit]}]]}]]
```